# Allow 1 hour only in day with PAM

Tags: linux, pam

How to allow user to access system only 1 hour in day using PAM?

For example I wish to give access to a user only for 1hr on a workstation in 24hrs. First the 24hr time period needs to be defined, as fixed time period like 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 or the time period should be counted from the time the user first logs in. One must also consider the possibility if the user logs in for 3 minutes. logs off and logs in, after an hour.

Note: I have successfully configure allow access in time ranges but not only 1 hour in day.

Please give me any example of any service.

Comment: Do keep in mind that pam only affects logins. So, once a user is logged in, she can stay logged in forever.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're best bet is [pam-script](http://freecode.com/projects/pam_script). You can write arbitrary scripts which will pass or fail. You can then configure pam to appropriately pass or fail the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set it using pam.d/time.conf

with a time of 0000 hours to 2359 hours.

Probably a  shell script that cold be written that

pipe out the login time duration each time the user is login to a file 
each time a user logins again compare the time from both logins.
so adding up of  period 1 + 2  during period 3 login period. If time exceed the stipulated amount kick the user out.